# How often do English speakers mishear an important and unimportant?

Tags: pronunciation, connected-speech

I know it's silly, but it's been bugging me for a while. Namely, the word unimportant and combination "an important". Whenever I pronounce them I cant' get rid of a feeling that they sound the same, at least when speaking fast.

Do native English speaker ever notice this perceived similarity?

Comment: Why not "an unimportant"?

Answer (score 1):

**an** and **un** have distinctly different vowels, and the prosody, the intonation/stress and rhythms,  is different as well between *an important* and *unimportant*.  Perhaps in a noisy room there might be some difficulty, but the syntax of the sentence would clear up doubts. A listener would have to miss most of what was said in order to have doubts in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

I think context separates them most times. I can't actually think of an instance in which it wouldn't.

Even if you reduce the first vowel to nothing more than an undifferentiated schwa Ə ...

If someone just said

> I think that's an important

& then stopped, I would immediately re-think & accept they'd said unimportant... because they didn't say an important **what**.

No-one would ever say

> I think that's unimportant idea.

so as soon as you have a noun following, then they said **an important**.

Comment: “That’s an/unimportant detail” is the one counter example I can come up with. It’s the context that matters not really whether a noun comes after important.

Comment: @ColleenV - I can't compensate for ellipsis :P [Yes, you're right... but it's going to be pretty rare]

Comment: Uh it's not ellipsis -  Be sure to indicate if that's an important detail. Don't bother me with unimportant detail, just give me the broad strokes. "Detail" can be both countable and uncountable.